# How to split a string in java by using following String?

Tags: java

How to split the following string How to split following string "LLSlotBook17-07-2015@Friday@1@10.00AM-12.00PM@10@LMV,mCWG" with ',' and '@'

Comment: You will find a lot of possible ways at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java

Answer (score 2):

You can use **String.split(regexp)** function :

```
String[] array = "LLSlotBook17-07-2015@Friday@1@10.00AM-12.00PM@10@LMV,mCWG".split(",|@");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should prefer the String.split method as mentioned by VLef,
but for the sake of completeness:

```
String s = "LLSlotBook17-07-2015@Friday@1@10.00AM-12.00PM@10@LMV,mCWG";
int x = s.indexOf("@");
String sub = s.substring(0, x);
```

will give you the first substring "LLSlotBook17-07-2015".

See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: Better as a comment... and please explain a bit to him so that he can understand further...

Comment: First, there are no code-tags in comments, and secondly the explanation is given in the link.